# How does WP BuddyPress integrate with CiviCRM Members?

Tags: wordpress, civimember, buddypress

I read from Tim Otten on this stack that "WP BuddyPress is a substantial system which has an upcoming Civi integration." Could someone tell me more about it ? I am on the verge to install BuddyPress because it seems easier to use but I want my data to integrate to CiviCRM in any case. Is it possible now or will it be and when ?

Answer (score 5):

I believe it's related to this post: https://civicrm.org/blogs/haystack/working-civicrm-46-wordpress that also notes the BuddyPress Groups Sync: 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/bp-groups-civicrm-sync/